# VS2015's npm support can't deal with @types?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, npm

I just found out that VS2015 has support for npm even in normal ASP.NET 4 projects - that's great.

The first thing I tried after `jquery` was to get types:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "aspnet",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34"
  }
}
```

This says

```
npm ERR! 404 'types/jquery' is not in the npm registry.
```

I know it is, because executing

```
npm install
```

in the directory of the `package.json` file then installs it correctly.

That's a bug in VS2015's npm support, right? Is there a fix?

Comment: What version of VS2015 are you using? Works for me in Update 3.

Comment: @DavidSherret Hmmm, I do have Update 3 also.